# Brillouin Zone Corresponding to Unit Cells

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

I was reading the book 'The Oxford Solid State Basics', Book by Steven H. Simon. The section explaining Brillouin zones had this paragraph in it

> Each Brillouin zone has exactly the same total area (or volume in
> three dimensions). This must be the case since there is a one-to-
> one mapping of points in each Brillouin zone to the first Brillouin
> zone. Finally, as in one dimension, we claim that there are exactly
> as many k-states within the first Brillouin zone as there are unit
> cells in the entire system.

Here I'm confused as to what they meant by

> as many k-states within the first Brillouin zone as there are unit
> cells in the entire system.

There would only be one unit cell in the system right?

Comment: No, we are only allowed to use Bloch's theorem if the lattice is big enough to have many unit cells in all 3 directions. Then we are to mentally continue the lattice to be of infinitely many unit cells in all 3 directions, and then the periodicity is perfect and the analysis is simpler. But if we have finitely many unit cells, then the number of k-states in 1BZ is the same as the number of unit cells.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have N atoms with a separation $a$ in an one-dimensional lattice. The unit cell of the real space is defined by the vector $\mathbf a$ with $|\mathbf a| = a$. By definition, the first Brillouin zone is defined by $\mathbf G$, such that $$\mathbf {G\cdot a} = 2\pi \implies |\mathbf G| = \frac{2\pi}{a}$$

Now, for any vector $\mathbf {na}$ of the lattice, there is a $\mathbf k_n$, with $$|\mathbf k_n| = \frac{2\pi}{na}$$ such that $$\mathbf {k_n\cdot na} = 2\pi$$ The minimum possible value is $\mathbf k_N = \frac{2\pi}{Na}$

So, there are so many $k$ vectors as unit cells in the lattice.